# Send Email body and attachment content to a REST (system Email) API in Mule 4

Tags: json, csv, mule, dataweave

I am trying to implement a Rest API to send any type of email (with or without attachments) using SMTP connector. I want the system-email API to get the email content dynamically from a request body.

In my client application I am constructing the json structure as below.

```
%dw 2.0
import toBase64 from dw::core::Binaries
output application/json
---
{
  "body": {
    "fromAddress": "abcmule01@outlook.com",
    "toAddress": Mule::p('email.to') splitBy ",",
    "subject": Mule::p('email.subject'),
    "content": payload,
    "contentType": "text/html",
    "encoding": "UTF-8",
    "contentTransferEncoding": "Base64",
    "attachments": {
        "txtAttachment": vars.textPlain,
        "csvAttachment": vars.csvPayload
    },
    "smtpHost": Mule::p('smtp.host'),
    "smtpPort": Mule::p('smtp.port'),
    "smtpUser": Mule::p('smtp.username'),
    "smtpPassword": Mule::p('smtp.password')
  },
  "header": {
    "apiName": "test-email-flow",
    "apiVersion": "1.0",
    "transactionId": "test-12345",
    "correlationId": "test-12345"
  }
}
```

The functionality is working fine only for sending text attachments However, if I try to send CSV content, the content is not displaying correctly in the email attachment.

Just for testing, I am reading a CSV file and constructing the CSV content (vars.csvPayload) as below.

application/csv; charset=UTF-8; header="false"

```
Belinda Jameson,2017,Cushing House,148,3.52
Jeff Smith,2018,Prescott House,17-D,3.20
Sandy Allen,2019,Oliver House,108,3.48
```

And the request structure for attachment is coming as below after the transformation.

```
  "attachments": {
      "txtAttachment": "This is the email text attachment",
      "csvAttachment": [
        {
          "column_0": "Belinda Jameson",
          "column_1": "2017",
          "column_2": "Cushing House",
          "column_3": "148",
          "column_4": "3.52"
        },
        {
          "column_0": "Jeff Smith",
          "column_1": "2018",
          "column_2": "Prescott House",
          "column_3": "17-D",
          "column_4": "3.20"
        },
        {
          "column_0": "Sandy Allen",
          "column_1": "2019",
          "column_2": "Oliver House",
          "column_3": "108",
          "column_4": "3.48"
        }
      ]
    }
```

However when I pass the 'attachments' to email send component in system-email API it is not showing the csv content in correct format. Can you please help me constructing the request structure for the attachment?

Below is the xml config file for send email sub flow

```
        <sub-flow name="sapi-core-email-send-mail-implementation" doc:id="177de084-c73b-4be1-ab10-90479ca98d5d" >
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="207cdb76-fc5e-47b1-bebd-1cc75f50a5d0" >
            <ee:message >
            </ee:message>
            <ee:variables >
                <ee:set-variable variableName="emailTo" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
"deeps.test@test.net.au,deeps2@test.net.au" splitBy ","]]></ee:set-variable>
                <ee:set-variable variableName="port" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload.body.smtpPort]]></ee:set-variable>
                <ee:set-variable variableName="username" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload.body.smtpUser]]></ee:set-variable>
                <ee:set-variable variableName="password" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload.body.smtpPassword]]></ee:set-variable>
                <ee:set-variable variableName="host" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload.body.smtpHost]]></ee:set-variable>
            </ee:variables>
        </ee:transform>
        <set-payload value='#[payload.body.content replace /([\r,\t,\n,"\"])/ with ""]' doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="98c98bac-da72-4b9f-9207-5bab35ac228c" mimeType="text/html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
        <email:send doc:name="Send" doc:id="b3318d9e-e0ca-4750-9cb5-3bd7cb9ccdca" fromAddress="#[vars.requestBody.fromAddress]" toAddresses="#[vars.requestBody.toAddress]" subject="#[vars.requestBody.subject]" ccAddresses="#[vars.requestBody.ccAddress]" bccAddresses="#[vars.requestBody.bccAddress]" replyToAddresses="#[vars.requestBody.replyToAddress]" config-ref="Email_SMTP_Sapi_Core_Email">
            <email:body contentType="#[vars.requestBody.contentType]" encoding="#[vars.requestBody.encoding]" contentTransferEncoding="#[vars.requestBody.contentTransferEncoding]" >
            </email:body>
            <email:attachments ><![CDATA[#[vars.requestBody.attachments]]]></email:attachments>
        </email:send>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="7a8d82aa-a23e-4bf9-bbad-26deb046c92f" message="Email has been successfully sent"/>
    </sub-flow>
```

And the csv attachment content is coming as below in the email attachment

```
    ¬í sr java.util.ArrayListxÒ™Ça I sizexp   w   sr java.util.LinkedHashMap4ÀN\lÀû Z accessOrderxr java.util.HashMapÚÁÃ`Ñ F 
loadFactorI     thresholdxp?@     w      t column_0t Belinda Jamesont column_1t 2017t column_2t 
Cushing Houset column_3t 148t column_4t 3.52x sq ~ ?@     w      t column_0t 
Jeff Smitht column_1t 2018t column_2t Prescott Houset column_3t 17-Dt column_4t 3.20x sq ~ ?@     w      t column_0t Sandy Allent column_1t 2019t column_2t Oliver Houset column_3t 108t column_4t 3.48x x
```

csvPayload
[image]

test.csv
[image]

Comment: What does the attachment content look like in the email that is received? Can you as well share the xml config of the Email Send component?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have provided the additional details. Please check.

Comment: Can you share the snippet where you build the attachments variable?

Comment: I am just trying to read a csv file (test.csv) to construct csvPayload variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Built a quick sample flow for you.. Substitute the mail SMTP info and try with the configuration below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:tls="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls" xmlns:email="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email"
    xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
    xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email/current/mule-email.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls/current/mule-tls.xsd">
    <file:config name="File_Config" doc:name="File Config" doc:id="6c465807-159c-4d17-94e5-8882f8baa1dc" >
        <file:connection />
    </file:config>
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="d0708665-5ac5-4bd1-80fd-cf83b7c2da9d" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="9191" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <email:smtp-config name="Email_SMTP" doc:name="Email SMTP" doc:id="9d7e5139-1aed-4a4e-9cc7-1b8d0297d7c2" from="from@email.com">
        <email:smtps-connection host="smtp.gmail.com"  user="yourgmailaddress"  password="yourpwd" port="465" connectionTimeout="30" readTimeout="30" writeTimeout="30">
            <tls:context>
                <tls:trust-store insecure="true" />
            </tls:context>
        </email:smtps-connection>
    </email:smtp-config>
    <flow name="test-send-emailFlow" doc:id="462b24c4-f53b-4483-b9f4-609c4190e28c" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="e764fbc7-fd3e-4121-bdb5-94eb9819184e" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/sm"/>
        <file:read doc:name="Read" doc:id="ca92561e-1dfa-44d4-a962-59b1493c198d" config-ref="File_Config" path="path/to/file/test.csv"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="5d7da7cd-1951-4607-ac82-e2f9002716f2" >
            <ee:message >
            </ee:message>
            <ee:variables >
                <ee:set-variable variableName="attachFile" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
{
    "message": write(payload,"application/csv")
}
]]></ee:set-variable>
            </ee:variables>
        </ee:transform>
        <email:send doc:name="Send" doc:id="c2ab4dd1-5401-4b64-abe3-9a95af371a31" config-ref="Email_SMTP" subject="CSV File">
            <email:to-addresses >
                <email:to-address value='"toemail"' />
            </email:to-addresses>
            <email:body contentType="text/plain" encoding="UTF-8">
                <email:content ><![CDATA[#["Hello"]]]></email:content>
            </email:body>
            <email:attachments ><![CDATA[#[vars.attachFile]]]></email:attachments>
        </email:send>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

I was able to test your sample csv file just fine with this config.

======================================================================

**Input to the flow below**

```
{
    "attachments": {
        "txtAttachment": "This is the email text attachment",
        "csvAttachment": [{
                "column_0": "Belinda Jameson",
                "column_1": "2017",
                "column_2": "Cushing House",
                "column_3": "148",
                "column_4": "3.52"
            },
            {
                "column_0": "Jeff Smith",
                "column_1": "2018",
                "column_2": "Prescott House",
                "column_3": "17-D",
                "column_4": "3.20"
            },
            {
                "column_0": "Sandy Allen",
                "column_1": "2019",
                "column_2": "Oliver House",
                "column_3": "108",
                "column_4": "3.48"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Updated Flow processes the incoming JSON**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:tls="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls" xmlns:email="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email"
    xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
    xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email/current/mule-email.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls/current/mule-tls.xsd">
    <file:config name="File_Config" doc:name="File Config" doc:id="6c465807-159c-4d17-94e5-8882f8baa1dc" >
        <file:connection />
    </file:config>
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="d0708665-5ac5-4bd1-80fd-cf83b7c2da9d" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="9191" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <email:smtp-config name="Email_SMTP" doc:name="Email SMTP" doc:id="9d7e5139-1aed-4a4e-9cc7-1b8d0297d7c2" from="fromemail">
        <email:smtps-connection host="smtp.gmail.com"  user="youremailId"  password="yourpasswd" port="465" connectionTimeout="30" readTimeout="30" writeTimeout="30">
            <tls:context>
                <tls:trust-store insecure="true" />
            </tls:context>
        </email:smtps-connection>
    </email:smtp-config>
    <flow name="test-send-emailFlow" doc:id="462b24c4-f53b-4483-b9f4-609c4190e28c" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="e764fbc7-fd3e-4121-bdb5-94eb9819184e" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/sm"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="5d7da7cd-1951-4607-ac82-e2f9002716f2" >
            <ee:message >
            </ee:message>
            <ee:variables >
                <ee:set-variable variableName="attachFile" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
{
    "message": write((payload.attachments.csvAttachment map {
           ($ mapObject {
              ("column_$$"): $
           })
}),"application/csv", {"header":false})
}
]]></ee:set-variable>
            </ee:variables>
        </ee:transform>
        <email:send doc:name="Send" doc:id="c2ab4dd1-5401-4b64-abe3-9a95af371a31" config-ref="Email_SMTP" subject="CSV File">
            <email:to-addresses >
                <email:to-address value='"youremailaddress"' />
            </email:to-addresses>
            <email:body contentType="text/plain" encoding="UTF-8">
                <email:content ><![CDATA[#["Hello"]]]></email:content>
            </email:body>
            <email:attachments ><![CDATA[#[vars.attachFile]]]></email:attachments>
        </email:send>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: Thanks Salim, Yes. I am able to send the csv attachment correctly if am am constructing the csv content within the same flow. but I am facing issue while sending the CSV content over HTTP request call from client API to system-email API in a JSON payload. Since the system-email API should be able to send any type of attachments dynamically based on request, I am looking for a best way to construct the request to send any form of attachments over Rest API. Please suggest if there are any best approach to do this.

Comment: Sure.. So if the json that you have in the code is sent as input to the system API , you need to tweak the DW to change that to a CSV and then pass it on to the email send . I did that and tested it by sending the "attachments" json that you have in your question and i was able to send the email just fine with the csv attached to the same. I have added the updated flow below the original one that i had put in.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs. as per your comments, now I am writing the the csv content as application/csv while constructing the request itself Instead of making changes at system-email API,  This has resolved the issue. (attaching the code snippet)

Comment: Below changes has resolved the issue:

        "attachments": {
     "txtAttachment": vars.textPlain,
     "csvAttachment": write((vars.csvPayload),"application/csv", {"header":false})
    }

Comment: glad to hear that. Can you please accept the answer or recommend an edit to be made so that the answer can help someone else in future, in case they land upon a similar problem.